# Evernote Cloud SDK for iOS New Version

Tags: ios, evernote

Apple was Starting June 1, 2016 all apps submitted to the App Store must support IPv6-only networking.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a

Because the current SDK version is using the NSURLConnection, it does not support the IPv6-only network.

Therefore, the application will be rejected that are using the current SDK version.

Evernote need to develop a new version of the SDK that supports IPv6 using NSURLSession or CFNetwork APIs.

Posted in evernote web site of the forum, but there is no answer from the evernote.

We want to resolve to evernote in a hurry this important issue.

What should I do to hasten a solution to evernote?

Comment: You should both create an issue on the project's GitHub page, and contact their dev team at dev.evernote.com or on twitter at @evernote_dev.